# how to add a custom function to bpy.ops

Tags: python

I'm trying to make my own bpy.ops python function, like bpy.ops.hi() for example, or even bpy.someotherfunction().

I realize that the submodules are only "fakes" as it says in the ops.py file, and they all point to C++ functions, here's the class to create all bpy.something():

```
class BPyOps:
    """
    Fake module like class.

     bpy.ops
    """
    __slots__ = ()

    def __getattr__(self, module):
        """
        gets a bpy.ops submodule
        """
        if module.startswith('__'):
            raise AttributeError(module)
        return BPyOpsSubMod(module)

    def __dir__(self):

        submodules = set()

        # add this classes functions
        for id_name in dir(self.__class__):
            if not id_name.startswith('__'):
                submodules.add(id_name)

        for id_name in op_dir():
            id_split = id_name.split('_OT_', 1)

            if len(id_split) == 2:
                submodules.add(id_split[0].lower())
            else:
                submodules.add(id_split[0])

        return list(submodules)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<module like class 'bpy.ops'>"
```

so for now without even getting into submodules I'd like to first know how to make a custom bpy.something(),

it seems like all the module names are coming from op_dir(), which is defined in the beginning:

```
from _bpy import ops as ops_module

# op_add = ops_module.add
op_dir = ops_module.dir
```

but I can't seem to find "_bpy" anywhere, I tried doing a windows search in both the blender release folder and the source code, and I couldn't find it (yet).

SO I think the step to make a custom module is to edit _bpy.dir, but where is that ???? Is it in the blender source somewhere, or a compiled python file?

Comment: Could it be there is an `import bpy as _bpy` import you missed?

Comment: no... look at the entire file here:\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py.  I actually found in the source: blender\python\intern\bpy.c, which apparently "fakes" the _bpy python class:  * This file defines the '_bpy' module which is used by python's 'bpy' package
 * to access C defined builtin functions.
 * A script writer should never directly access this module.
 */, although I'm still not exactly sure where to find the ".dir" property of that to modify it